# accept fails with EFAULT

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have a socket server running on multiple machines. It works like a charm besides on **one** machine.

The server binds correctly but returns an error (EFAULT) when the client attempts to connect.

Perhaps someone has an idea what the source of the problem might be. Thanks a lot in advance!

Some information about the machine:
Linux version 2.6.18.3
gcc version 3.3.5 (Debian 1:3.3.5-13)

The socket server source is pretty straight forward.

```
...
...
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
struct sockaddr* client;
socklen_t alen;


sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd == -1) {
    ...
}

server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0){
    ...
}

if(listen(sockfd,BACKLOG) == -1){
    ...
}

alen = sizeof(client);

new_fd = accept(sockfd, client, &alen);
if (new_fd == -1) {
        /*
        * this part of the code is executed
        * errno is set to 14
        */
}
```

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
struct sockaddr_in client;
...
alen = sizeof(client);
new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &alen);
```

`accept` expects a pointer to an existing buffer which it'll fill in. You have two errors, you set alen to the size of a *pointer*, and you pass an uninitialized pointer to accept.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help Eric! Your suggestion resolved the issue. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

From the `accept(2)` man page:

> ```
>   EFAULT The addr argument is not in a writable part of the user  address
>           space.
> ```

Check to make sure that you've allocated `client` appropriately.